# Xdebug works with PhpStorm but not on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, phpstorm, xdebug

Just simple problem which I can't figure out. Just switched to VSCode for testing and want to set up debugger same as I have in PhpStorm.

Here are the current settings which I use that works in PhpStorm:

[image]

[image]

I use path mapping because of docker to specify remote directory.

Now switching to VSCode I have something like this but nothing is happening when I turn on debug, I switched `ideKey` to `VSCODE` in the container and in the browser extension setting and checked `phpinfo()` to verify.

Is there any setting in the VSCode which specifies ideKey as well that I'm missing or any other setting? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Just a note: 1) You should show your actual Xdebug settings as well. post your live settings from `xdebug_info();` output for Xdebug v3 (for Xdebug v2 that would be the whole Xdebug section from `phpinfo()` output). PhpStorm may invoke your debug request in a different way etc. 2) Enable Xdebug logging, try to debug and check the log -- it will tell if Xdebug tries to connect to the client (VSCode) or not, what the response is etc.

Comment: Also, the IDE key is irrelevant.